# jackrabbit error: can't create folder

Tags: linux, filesystems, aix, jackrabbit, jcr

I am using Jackrabbit version 1.6 on IBM AIX. It is similiar to Linux operating system. Jackrabbit is used to store files being uploaded by the users of my application. I get an error `"can't create a folder"` when the JCR has stored more than 32767 files/folders in the directory specified in the repository (in configuration file).

Has this problem been resolved in the latest version of Jackrabbit. I understand that this is the OS limit but with a tweak in the file storing mechanism of Jackrabbit this problem can be solved

Or

Is there a way that I can specify in the JCR confirgutation that it should store the files in some other directory once the 32767 limit is reached.

Or

Is there a way that I save the files monthwise/weekwise because I am sure that in one month I would have less than 32767 files.

Any help/comment is appreciated.

Thanks,

Tarik

Comment: In what directory are those files, and what are the file names? Also, what prevents you from upgrading to a somewhat recent version of Jackrabbit?

Comment: The directory name could be anything. The files being stored are named by Jackrabbit itself, all I get is a unique ID which I can refer to when I want to retrieve a file. The system is already LIVE in production, so shifting newer version of Jackrabbit is not trivial. Although if the problem is fixed in the latest version then we can move to newer version with special approvals.

Comment: Also moving to new version means that we would have to write a new migration process as the logic of generating unique id has been changed from version 1.6 to 2.4

Comment: "The directory name could be anything" - well, could you give an example? Are you using an old file based persistence manager? How does the logic of generating unique ids affect your program?

Comment: "well, could you give an example?" -  Jackrabbit is being loaded in Jboss application server as EAR and not as standalone app.  The repository is being defined at run time. The path used is /usr/local/myapp/submod1. "Are you using an old file based persistence manager?" - The configuration for the Persistence Manager is: <PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.xml.XMLPersistenceManager" />.

Comment: "How does the logic of generating unique ids affect your program?" - As my system is already in Production so the version 1.6 of Jackrabbit cannot be upgraded with the version 2.4 as the repository created in the earlier version is not compatible with the newer version. So we would have to write a migration process where each file would be retrieved from the older version and then uploaded in the newer version.

Comment: So you have 32767 files in the directory `/usr/local/myapp/submod1`? What are some of the file names of those 32767 files?

Comment: Yes, when the 32767 files are created, Jackrabbit throws an error: Could not create folder. These are arbitary names created by Jackrabbit. Does the file name have a significance. The point is that after 32767 files have been created Jackrabbit does not accept more files to be stored and I am looking for a solution for that.

Comment: I ask you now the 4th time: What are some of the file names of those 32767 files? Or maybe it's directory names. If you can't answer this question, just tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to not use the XMLPersistenceManager, because [if the JVM process is killed the repository might turn inconsistent](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ#XMLPersistenceManager). An alternative is to use a [Bundle Database PM](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ#Bundle_Database_PM).

To help migrate to a newer version of Jackrabbit, see the [Backup and Migration](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/BackupAndMigration) page.

Comment: The DB bundle cannot be used as per the early agreeement with the client. So, I am stuck with filesystem only.

Comment: Is there a way that I can store the files monthwise because I for sure know that I won't have more than 32767 files in a month. Can I do this with some configuration in Jackrabbit

Comment: We have tried the newer version of Jackrabbit as well. The problem of 32767 elements exists there as well. So finally we are planning to migrate from 1.6 to 2.4 and use DB. Is there a tool which we can use to migrate the repository from 1.6 file based to 2.4 DB based.

Comment: @TarikSingh I'm not sure if you read my answer, there is a link to the Backup and Migration docs. Other than that I'm afraid I don't know other tools.

Comment: Sorry, Thomas, I got the answer in the API. Thanks for the help!